# Create text file download/update into a particular location in local client machine using JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I want to create a text file using JavaScript and store in a particular location in my system, Suppose I want to store in:

`C:\Users\RAJ\Desktop`

I have found an interesting API [Link](https://github.com/rndme/download)

It creates and simply download the file but I can not specify the location.

please guide me how I can download into a particular location?

Note: If a file already exists in same name then it should replace with the new file.

Comment: Won't be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This activity is prevented due to security. Consider if the browser was allowed to be scripted to download and replace any file on your computer. For this reason, the browser will either prompt or use the Users defined preference to download content to a specific folder. You cannot script where a download will go on the users computer.